# Dropdown menu from table row in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, html-table, row, jasny-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu working from a table row using the Jasny extension found http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/#rowlink. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work to display a dropdown. I have en example of what I've done so far:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Heading
        </th>
        <th>
            Heading
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-provides="rowlink">
    <tr class="rowlink">
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Click For Dropdown Menu
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li>
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Action
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Another action
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Click For Dropdown Menu
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cell
        </td>
        <td>
            Cell
        </td>    
    </tr>         
</tbody>
</table>​
```

Clicking row will follow href link, instead of displaying the dropdown menu.
I can get the rowlink extension to work as a link or to call a modal window.
I can also get a dropdown to come from a single cell (without jasny extension), but would like it to work from the whole row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately rowlink only works with the href and doesn't propogate js events. So it can't be used for dropdowns.

Having a closer look dropdown code, shows that after the dropdown is initialized a click on dropdown-toggle doesn't do much more than toggle the 'open' class. We can easily mimic that. Now we just need to make sure dropdown is initialized on load instead of on click and presto :)

Note that I'm only using the rowlink css (not js) for the pointer and link style.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr class="rowlink">
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle rowlink" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Click For Dropdown Menu
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li>
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Action
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Another action
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Click For Dropdown Menu
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>         
</tbody>
</table>​

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

        $('.rowlink').on('click', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*P.S. This jsfiddle kept crashing my browser :s*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have to admit jsfiddle was quite sluggish for me too!

Comment: I've also been looking a little at how the dropdown works & how yours works too. I'll give your code a go. :-)

Comment: It works, but only if I click the first cell, & it also appears at the bottom of the table! It's a good start though. I think I'll have to have a good play to see how I can get the dropdown to work from the whole row & appear below the current cell being clicked. If I find a solution I'll let you know. Would be cool to see it included in your Jasny extension for others to use. After a good searching on the web I've realised I'm not the only one looking for this functionality! :-)

Comment: It will work for the first cell without much javascript. I should work on the second cell as well (I tested it with Chrome).

Answer (score 8):

set

```
<td style="overflow:visible">
```

it works.

Comment: This helped me fix this problem of the dropdown menu being hidden.

Answer (score 8):

**Bootstrap 3.x**

By default Bootstrap dropdowns inside a table cell doesn't show up properly (they would show up at the bottom of the page). To fix this you need to set class for the container as dropdown. For table cells, this would look like this:

```
<td class="dropdown">
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/sytelus/kzxes29r/

PS: If you don't want to change style for table cell, you can also create a div inside cell and set its class to "dropdown".

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming Above works for Bootstrap 3.x but not for 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this::

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{font-family:arial;}
table{font-size:80%;background:black}
a{color:black;text-decoration:none;font:bold}
a:hover{color:#606060}
td.menu{background:lightblue}
table.menu
{
font-size:100%;
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
function showmenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
}
function hidemenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Drop down menu</h3>
<table width="100%">
 <tr bgcolor="#FF8080">
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('tutorials')" onmouseout="hidemenu('tutorials')">
   <a href="/default.asp">Tutorials</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="tutorials" width="120">
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/xml/default.asp">XML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/xsl/default.asp">XSL</a></td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('scripting')" onmouseout="hidemenu('scripting')">
   <a href="/default.asp">Scripting</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="scripting" width="120">
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/vbscript/default.asp">VBScript</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="default.asp">DHTML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/asp/default.asp">ASP</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/ado/default.asp">ADO</a></td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td onmouseover="showmenu('validation')" onmouseout="hidemenu('validation')">
   <a href="/site/site_validate.asp">Validation</a><br>
   <table class="menu" id="validation" width="120">
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/web/web_validate.asp">Validate HTML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/web/web_validate.asp">Validate XHTML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/web/web_validate.asp">Validate CSS</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/web/web_validate.asp">Validate XML</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td class="menu"><a href="/web/web_validate.asp">Validate WML</a></td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<p>Mouse over these options to see the drop down menus</p>
</body>

</html>
```